# Galaxy Note II USB connection not working

Tags: usb, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-note-2

On my Galaxy Note II (android 4.1.1), any time I try to connect to something over USB, it doesn't seem to want to connect. Specifically:

-iSyncr gives me errors connecting; so does Android File Transfer

-DoubleTwist and EasyPhoneSync can't connect at all

-Odin gets stuck at "Making Connection" (or something, I can't remember the exact wording)

These problems occur whether I have USB debugging on or not, and still persist when I mess around with the MTP/PTP settings. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? iSyncr used to work fine, but the others have always been broken.

Note: this is on a mac, and Odin is run through a virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android?

As of JellyBean 4.2.2, you'd need a newer version of ADB, as there's a security implementation built into JB 4.2.2, in that, any "unauthorised" computer with USB cable plugged in, will show the device as offline, rendering any file transfer/copying etc useless.

With the new version of ADB as downloaded from Google or for your device, you will be prompted to request authorisation and to allow it, based on a cryptographic key generated by ADB so that the computer is "trusted", then the contents can be copied/transferred.

Comment: Nope, I'm on 4.1.1.

Comment: Should have stated it on your question - kindly please re-edit to include your comment :)